# Computing Riemannian integrals from paritions.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need help understanding how does one show definite Riemannian integration from $a$ to $b$ directly from sums if $a,b$ are not given. The text I am working from talks about odd and even functions and recommends trying on $f(x) = x^2$ and $f(x) = x^3$ on any closed interval $[a,b]$.

I know I need to arrive at $\lim U(f,P_n) = \lim L(f,P_n)$, but I am not sure how to show that properly with careful *rigorous* proofs how to do that. Moreover, it seems that text implies that I need to use even/odd properties of the functions somehow, which confuses me. The text only has an example for linear case, and non-rigorous example showing how Riemannian integration works at all in principle. (Without using Fundamental Theorem).

I would really appriciate a demonstration of how to do that in principle on these two functions above. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try exactly the same approach as used for linear case and let us know where you are facing the problem.